# I need help to "fine tune" my batch script (adding IF statements)

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I have to:

1. Copy a .doc file from a location to another
2. Rename it at the new location (adding the current date to the name)
3. Open the location where the copied/renamed file is now located
4. Play a confirmation sound

The (rudimentary) batch script below that relies on a small player (BP) to play the sound, works nicely for the 4 above points.

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\Some Path\Doc.doc" "D:\My Documents\" /q /y /k /r /h
ren "D:\My Documents\Doc.doc" "New Word Document (%date%).doc"
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
start "" /b /wait "D:\My Documents\"
BP /play /close /embedding .\1.wav
exit
```

I would like to ask somebody who (unlike me) is familiar with scripts to help me to add some IF statements, namely:

- Ref point 2 above: If the `"New Word Document (%date%).doc"` file already exists at that location, the `xcopy` and the `ren` commands should be skipped (but the rest should continue).

and

- Ref point 3 above: If the folder `"D:\My Documents\"` is already open the `start` command should be skipped (but the rest should continue).

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [How to verify if a file exists in a Windows .BAT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022176/how-to-verify-if-a-file-exists-in-a-windows-bat-file) and [If Not Exist - CMD Command - Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780553/if-not-exist-cmd-command-not-working)

```
IF NOT EXIST "D:\My Documents\New Word Document (%date%).doc" (
  xcopy "C:\Some Path\Doc.doc" "D:\My Documents\" /q /y /k /r /h
  ren "D:\My Documents\Doc.doc" "New Word Document (%date%).doc"
)
```

For the second part you seem to be out of luck, according to ["Bring to front" for Windows XP command shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557166/bring-to-front-for-windows-xp-command-shell)

Comment: @ Micha: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and for the links you provided (nice tips).

Comment: Thanks to your tip I improved my script like this: IF EXIST "D:\My Documents\New Word Document (%date%).doc" (goto PLACE) else goto OTHER PLACE... In this way it makes me even happier :D